# Does Media Foundation transforms support ARM in Windows 8?

Tags: arm, windows-8, ms-media-foundation

Does Media Foundation transforms support ARM in Windows 8 ?
how to load a decdoer.dll for arm？
I write a decoder， it can use in x86 version, and called by Media extensions sample.
but the arm version dll cannot be loaded by app(arm metro app).

thank you very much!

Comment: Good question, I also like to know this! Do you get some error messages or is it just not loading?

Comment: consider [edit]ing the question to include details that you put into [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11060352/839601) and in comments below it

Comment: It will def not work with a decoder.dll compiled for x86. The real question is whether the Media Foundation namespace is available when compiling for ARM